# How to parse a stream as it's been fed to MediaPlayer?

Tags: android

I'm tinkering with a very simple streaming web radio player, using MediaPlayer's (relatively new) stream URL methods, something like:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();        
mp.setDataSource("http://stream.infowars.com");
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

(exception handling omitted here for simplicity)

This works real well (and even better after recent upgrade to 2.3.4 - no more drop-outs :-)

It is my understanding that many web radio streams have embedded song titles. I want to be able to parse the steam as it goes by and pick off the song title text so as to display it on-screen.

I know I could probably do this the old-fashioned way (pre Android 2) - by manually opening the file and parsing it as I manually feed to MediaPlayer, but this would entail a whole lot of work that I'd rather avoid (unless there's no other way).

I'm guessing I could probably also get to these embedded tags by opening a second instance of the same stream, just for reading, but of course this is way inefficient and too much overhead.

Can anybody point me in the right direction? Is this even possible??
TIA